# Refer to the targeted language when clicking on Navbar.link in React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a problem regarding `Nav.Link` in react-bootstrap, I have a mobile nav with some links wrapped with `Nav.Link` like this :

`<Nav.Link href='/news'>{t("news")}</Nav.Link>`

when I change the language to Arabic and press a link , it navigates to the English version instead of the Arabic one. I have tried the below but it is the same:

```
<Nav.Link href={`${i18n.language}/news\`}>{t("news")}</Nav.Link>
```

And

```
<Nav.Link href={i18n.language+"/news"}>{t("news")}</Nav.Link>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you checked if `i18n.langugae` is getting updated on language change?

Comment: I solved it  , I missed adding '/' at the beginning of the href like this:            
 `<Nav.Link href={`/${i18n.language}/news`} >{t("News")} </Nav.Link>`